# How do I get the results (selected columns) from a query, without inserting them into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a written a code.

1. I  don't want to insert the values into a new table or existing table, but i do want to display the selected columns of the multiple tables.
2. I want a add a date filter using variables so that it picks up the date automatically without me hard coding the date values.

The logic is this:

I have the previous value as:  if the downtime_in_mins value is greater than zero then i have to take the previous value and take it as a reference.

I have the next value as:   if the downtime_in_mins value is greater than zero then i have taken the next value.

The values are grouped by the task_number as well.

the values are taken on the basis of datetime and task_number.

```
declare @pdate datetime
declare @previous_value FLOAT
declare @next_value FLOAT
DECLARE @end_time datetime
declare @loopdate datetime
declare @padid varchar(10)
declare @dc_dc float
declare @tasknumber nvarchar(50)
set @loopdate = '2001-01-01'
set @pdate = '2016-10-01 01:00:00'

SET @tasknumber = '0'

while exists ( select   DCDC_OUTPUT_AVG,TASK_NUMBER
from I_TASK T, I_HOURLY_DATA F,I_DATE D, I_SITE_LOCATION P
where F.D_DATE = D.ID AND F.D_PWM_LOCATION = P.ID 
AND T.SITE_ID like P.NAME+'%' 

AND D.DATE_KEY between cast(TASK_CREATION_DATE as date) 
AND dateadd("d",1,CAST( coalesce(ACCEPTED_DATE, working_date) AS DATE)) 
and task_priority > '01' and TASK_PRIORITY <'06' 
and TASK_CLOSED_DATE between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-01' 
and TASK_NUMBER > @tasknumber
)

Begin 

select top 1  @pdate=DATEADD(hour, D_TIME_OF_DAY-1, d.date_key), @tasknumber = t.TASK_NUMBER
from I_TASK T, I_HOURLY_DATA F,I_DATE D, I_SITE_LOCATION P
where F.D_DATE = D.ID AND F.D_PWM_LOCATION = P.ID AND T.SITE_ID like P.NAME+'%' AND D.DATE_KEY between cast(TASK_CREATION_DATE as date)  AND 
dateadd("d",1,CAST( coalesce(ACCEPTED_DATE, working_date) AS DATE)) and
task_priority > '01' and TASK_PRIORITY <'06' 
and TASK_CLOSED_DATE between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-01' and DOWNTIME_IN_MINS  >0
    and TASK_NUMBER > @tasknumber
order by task_number, SITE_ID, TASK_CREATION_DATE, d.Date_key, D_TIME_OF_DAY


print 'testing'
print @pdate
print @tasknumber

select top 1  @previous_value=DCDC_OUTPUT_AVG
from I_TASK T, I_HOURLY_DATA F,I_DATE D, I_SITE_LOCATION P
where F.D_DATE = D.ID AND F.D_PWM_LOCATION = P.ID AND T.SITE_ID like P.NAME+'%' AND D.DATE_KEY between cast(TASK_CREATION_DATE as date)  AND 
dateadd("d",1,CAST( coalesce(ACCEPTED_DATE, working_date) AS DATE)) and
task_priority > '01' and TASK_PRIORITY <'06' 
and TASK_CLOSED_DATE between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-01'  AND DATEADD(hour, D_TIME_OF_DAY-1, d.date_key) = DATEADD("HH",-1,@pdate)    and task_number=@tasknumber
    
print @previous_value
print DATEADD("HH",-1,@pdate)

select top 1 @next_value=DCDC_OUTPUT_AVG, @end_time=DATEADD(hour, D_TIME_OF_DAY-1, d.date_key)
from I_TASK T, I_HOURLY_DATA F,I_DATE D, I_SITE_LOCATION P
where F.D_DATE = D.ID AND F.D_PWM_LOCATION = P.ID AND T.SITE_ID like P.NAME+'%' AND D.DATE_KEY between cast(TASK_CREATION_DATE as date)  AND 
dateadd("d",1,CAST( coalesce(ACCEPTED_DATE, working_date) AS DATE)) and
task_priority > '01' and TASK_PRIORITY <'06' 
and TASK_CLOSED_DATE between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-10' and DCDC_OUTPUT_AVG>=0.6*@previous_value  
AND DATEADD(hour, D_TIME_OF_DAY-1, d.date_key) > @pdate     and TASK_NUMBER=@tasknumber


print @next_value
print datediff("hh", @pdate, @end_time)

SET @loopdate = @pdate

End
```

Output:

```
DCDC_OUTPUT_AVG||   @pdate=DATEADD(hour, D_TIME_OF_DAY-1, d.date_key)  || task_number   || @next_value  ||  @previous_Value
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want... This sounds like *I'm missing a front end*...

Comment: @Shnugo: I have written the code and its working fine. I am unable to get the output in a table. if i give a print statement then i am able to see the output. I want to have the output in rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement looks so - uhm - "2000ish" :-)

You are using *old-fashioned-join* syntax with comma separated table names and their join condition in the `WHERE` clause.

You are walking the *procedural* line... And you are using SQL like it was kind of `BASIC` :-)

If you fetch the values with solitair queries from a loop you'll get many isolated results. Obviously you are aware of the possibility to insert these results into a table to get a combined result.

> I don't want to insert the values into a new table or existing table

Why?
Are you aware of *declared table variables* You can declare a volatile table, fill it and read it as any other table, but it will vanish when out of scope:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES('First entry'),('Second Entry');
SELECT TableAlias.ID
      ,TableAlias.SomeValue 
FROM @dummy AS TableAlias
```

which returns

```
ID  SomeValue
1   First entry
2   Second Entry
```

### Solution 1 (bad approach, but low impact)

Declare a table variable with the needed structure and use `INSERT` statements within your loop to collect your results

### Solution 2 (much better)

Re-do your query. Let it be *set-based* (no loops or `CURSOR`) and modern `JOIN`-syntax. Use variables instead of literals.